# Activerecord find_by_sql does not output SQL query results

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, find-by-sql

I am using `activerecord` and `find_by_sql` to output the results of the sql query:

```
S = Object.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM foo")
S.each do |s|
  puts "#{s}"
end
```

I get

```
#<Object:0x0000010214d5e0>
#<Object:0x0000010214ce60>
```

etc...

I need the actual results.

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: From your description, it looks like it's working properly, what were you expecting?

Comment: what are the attributes that you select with `SELECT *` ? If one of the attributes is e.g. a `name`, then you can call `s.name`, etc

Answer (score 3):

The ActiveRecord [`find_by_sql`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000337) function expects that the query will return values from the underlying table of the class that it was invoked upon. For example, if you have a class called `Foo` (with underlying table `foos` with columns `bar` and `baz`) you could do this:

```
Foo.find_by_sql("select * from foos").each do |record|
    puts "Got a Foo: bar=#{record.bar}, baz=#{record.baz}"
end
```

If the problem is that you don't like the output you are getting when you try to print out an object (`#<Object:0x0000010214d5e0>`), then you need only create a `to_s` method on your class:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    def to_s
        "Foo bar=#{record.bar}, baz=#{record.baz}"
    end
end
```

Alternately, don't print the object directly (`"#{s}"`), use `inspect`:

```
puts s.inspect
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want just the raw unprocessed data from an arbitrary SQL query, you should be using [`select_rows`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_rows) thusly:

```
SomeModel.connection.select_rows('select * from foo').each do |row|
  # `row` is an array of strings at this point
  puts row.join(', ')
end
```

You'll have to sort out type conversions and such yourself but sometimes all the ActiveRecord machinery just gets in the way so you can work with raw SQL and results as needed.

Comment: Awesome! ... Is there a way to know the name of the columns returned? (find_by_sql and other activerecord methods fail when I have "left join" in my sql statement)

Comment: @Abdo: Not with `select_rows`, that simply returns one array for each row and the elements of the row-arrays come in the same order as the SELECT columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `to_s` method for that object.
You can try `puts s.inspect` or `p s` instead

Answer (score 0):

`puts` converts ruby object into string by invoking to_s method on object.
The default `to_s` prints the object's class and an encoding of the object id.
In order to print human readable form of object use `inspect`

```
locs = Location.find_by_sql('select * from locations')
  Location Load (0.5ms)  select * from locations


locs.each do |l|
  # it calls to_s method on object
  puts l
end

#<Location:0x000000055bb328>
#<Location:0x000000055bb058>

locs.each do |l|
  puts l.inspect # prints actual object
end

#<Location id: 15, name: "Annettaside3", street: "71838 Ritchie Cape", city: "East Destanystad", state: "Utah", zip: "58054", phone: 123456, other_phone: 987654, staff_strength: 40, is_active: true, created_at: "2012-01-25 11:17:26", updated_at: "2012-01-25 11:17:26", country_name: "Korea">
#<Location id: 16, name: "Sporerbury4", street: "73057 Jerad Shoal", city: "South Kyliefurt", state: "Delaware", zip: "46553-3376", phone: 123456, other_phone: 987654, staff_strength: 40, is_active: true, created_at: "2012-01-25 11:24:48", updated_at: "2012-01-25 11:24:48", country_name: "Australia">
```